# keystone, cert_required and nova

Tags: ssl, openstack, pki, keystone

I'm trying to configure Keystone in my OpenStack setup to use SSL. I'm currently playing with `cert_required` flag in `keystone.conf`:

```
[ssl]
enable = True
certfile = /etc/keystone/ssl/certs/signing_cert.pem
keyfile = /etc/keystone/ssl/private/signing_key.pem
ca_certs = /etc/keystone/ssl/certs/ca.pem
cert_required = True
```

Unfortunately if it's set to `True` I'm unable to connect to nova using it's CLI client:

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

In keystone CLI client I can specify `--os-key` and `--os-cert` options to do a proper SSL handshake and then it works. These options are missing in nova CLI client. How can I use `cert_required` option with nova? Maybe the option is prepared to be used in other scenarios?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps Super User or Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Try cert_required = False and use --insecure to avoid client cert validation.